# MySQL split cell into multiple rows but copying the remaining row data

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a table like the following:

```
|  SKU    | Manufacturer | Qty
|-----------------------------|
|  12345  | GE, Sony     | 10
|  123456 | GE           | 25
```

We need to split the rows where more than one manufacturer is listed, and copy the remaining row data (SKU is not unique). So the expected results would be following:

```
|  SKU    | Manufacturer | Qty
|-----------------------------|
|  12345  | GE           | 10 |
|  12345  | Sony         | 10 |
|  123456 | GE           | 25 |
```

Can this be even done with MySQL, if so the how? If not, what would other options be then?

Comment: will you use that data somewhere like PHP? it's easier to do it there.

Comment: Hope you've now learned to never, ever store data as comma separated items...

Comment: You should search before asking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows

Comment: Curious , don't you end up overstating the sku qty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the answer:

```
CREATE TABLE Temp (SKU INT, Manufacturer VARCHAR(15),Qty INT);
INSERT INTO Temp VALUES(12345,'GE, Sony',10);
INSERT INTO Temp VALUES(123456,'GE',25);

select
  Temp.SKU,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Temp.Manufacturer, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1) Manufacturer,
  Temp.Qty
from
  (select 1 n union all
   select 2 union all select 3 union all
   select 4 union all select 5) numbers INNER JOIN Temp
  on CHAR_LENGTH(Temp.Manufacturer)
     -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(Temp.Manufacturer, ',', ''))>=numbers.n-1
order by
  SKU, n
```

Check with [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ce04/2)